# How to use javascript variable in Web worker thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, worker-thread

I need to update my javascript array in Web worker thread.
I cannot accces my javascript array in Web worker thread.

My code is :

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
var array = new Uint8Array(event.data);
var sum = 0;
var temparray = new Array();

for(var list = 0; list < array.length; list++ ){
    var temp = myMethod(array[list]); //some operation
    availableArray.push(temp);
}

 self.postMessage("success");
}
```

I am getting this error:
availableArrayis undefined
availableArray.push(temp);

Comment: looks like you didn't declare availableArray, is there a `availableArrays = []` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I defined availableArray in some other js file which already doing some operation. I need to update that array from worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You define 2 variables that are arrays (or array-like objects): `var array = new Uint8Array` and `var temparray = new Array`, but then in the loop you use a variable that isn't declared anywhere `availableArray`, I suspect you want to change that variable to `temparray`.
The error message makes perfect sense: `availableArray` is not defined anywhere. You're using it as an array, and invoking the `push` method on it. However, JS, by default, creates a new variable for you whenever you use a var that hasn't been declared. The default value for a non-initialized variable is, of course, `undefined`. `undefined` doesn't have a `push` method, hence the error.

However, just a slight remark, though: in JS `new Array` is actually discouraged. Best use the array literal notation:

```
var temparray = [];
```

It's shorter *and* safer.

Comment: But I defined availableArray in some other js file. I need to update that array from my worker thread. Is this possible to update an array or any variable which already doing some operation?

Comment: @Prasath: A worker isn't a pure thread as you'd have in C/C++. It does not share state, but runs completely separate from the main JS thread. If you want to update the `availableArray`, you'll have to send a message to the main JS process, and update the data there